# What type of anchor is this and what is the max capacity ?

Tags: drywall, mounting, drywall-anchor, mount

I want to mount an item that is pretty heavy on the wall but the studs don't align with where I would like to mount it.   Here is a picture I the anchor I am using (using two of them):

[image]

What type of anchor is this? And how much weight can it hold ? (Given evenly distributed weight and standard drywall)

Comment: What is the approx. weight of the item? And what is the size of the anchor in the  photo?

Comment: If this weighs more than 50 pounds or is subject to any dynamic load, strongly consider shifting to a mounting onto studs. If that is not possible, consider toggle type anchors.

Comment: Is that color dark blue or dark grey?

Comment: Looks to be dark blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a "Triple Grip" brand anchor. I have similar anchors.  The box says 77 pounds in 5/8 inch drywall.  No specification for 1/2 inch.

[[image: Instructions]

[image: Box Cover]

Comment: That looks like it! Is it 77lbs per anchor or total with two anchors? Thanks for the quick answer +1

Comment: That's per anchor, but it's for 5/8" drywall.  1/2" is more common.  I'd say in 1/2" drywall, you could hang 80 pounds if the screws are on opposite sides of a stud.

Comment: @ZeroStack I can't say for sure with this particular product, but in my experience differently-colored products of the same type, from the same manufacturer, usually denote different size/capabilities. So while Edwin's are rated for 70 lbs, it may be the case that yours (which are gray, not blue) are rated for a different weight.

Comment: @DanC You are spot on.  i just looked at my box of TripleGrip anchors and they are light grey colored (not OP's shade of grey) and are rated for 100 lbs.

Comment: The OP's look blue on my screen, but it could be grey. The chart on the first pic in my answer says the the grey one's are rated for 51 lbs.

Answer (score 0):

That would be an expanding wall anchor. They are available in  several sizes, the larger the size the more weight they can support.

It is difficult to judge the size of the anchor in your photo. If you can include an object that it's size can be compared to would help.

You hadn't mentioned the items weight, but if it is heavier than 30-40 pounds you should consider a different fastener. I've found toggle bolts to be able to support very heavy items, especially for gypsum paneled walls. The metal expanding wings (toggle) grip the back of the wall board when the screw is tightened.

The next most reliable wall anchor for drywall would be a [drywall screw](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L0CM3AW) . They are available in plastic or metal. The metal can support more weight. They easily screw into a hollow bay behind drywall panels with a drill.

If you feel unsure that a single anchor can support the items full weight you can always configure the attachment points to include 2-3 anchors. This will considerably lessen the weight each anchor will support.

Comment: What you list as the second alternative are NOT [*drywall screws*](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Grip-Rite-8-x-1-5-8-in-Philips-Bugle-Head-Coarse-Thread-Sharp-Point-Drywall-Screw-158cdws1/100112584) but rather anchors for drywall. *Drywall screws* are only suitable for holding drywall to framing.